# I'm not able to connect with database using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm not able to connect with database using jquery ajax.

**The below is the login1.html page**

```
    <form method='POST'>
                <div class="username">
                    <input type="text" id='name' name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your username">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="password">
                    <input type="password" id='password' name='password' class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i>
                </div>
                <div id="error"></div>
                <div class="custom-radio-checkbox">
                    <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" class="bluecheckradios">
                    <label>Remember me</label>
                </div>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                      $('.bluecheckradios').iCheck({
                        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue',
                        radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue',
                        increaseArea: '20%' // optional
                      });
                    });     
                </script>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary style2" name='submit' id="submit" value="Sign In">
            </form>
```

**The form value is transferred through jquery ajax**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

   // jQuery methods go here...


$('#submit').click(function(){

    var username = $('#name').val();
    var pass = $('#password').val();

    var datastring = {username:username,pass:pass};
    if($.trim(username).length>0 && $.trim(pass).length>0){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "process/login.php",
        data : datastring,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend : function(){
            $("#submit").val('Connectiing...');
        },
        success:function(data){
            if(data){
                window.location.href('http://www.google.com');
            }
            else{
                $('#loginone').shake();
                $('#submit').val('Login')
                $("#error").html("<span style='color:red'>Error:</span>Invalid Username or Password");
            }
        }

        });
    }
return false;

});

});

</script>
```

** This is the data connection page process/login.php**

```
<?php

    include_once('config.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $sql = "select id from login where login_name = '".$username."' and login_password = '".$pass."' ";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if($result->num_row > 0){

            echo "connected";
        }



    }//EOF SUBMIT

?>
```

**When ever i pass the correct credentials i get an error for wrong username and password.**

Comment: maybe your ajax not having `submit` input and u are using `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` in php and sending just `var datastring = {username:username,pass:pass};`

Comment: change `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` as `if(count($_POST) > 0)` will work

Comment: What's your XHR response content ? Check what's you are getting in ```data``` in ```success:function(data){```

Comment: now u have few solutions try them

Comment: strange but none of them is working :-(

Comment: really? what r u getting in `print_r($_POSt)`

Comment: i don't know what happen now, both the if and else blocks are working whether the id or password is correct or incorrect.

Comment: The values that i get from print_r($_POST) is :-  Array ( [username] => ftg [pass] => gf  )

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending the value of the submit over the ajax change your if to

```
 if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['pass']) ){
```

or add the value to the ajax:

```
datastring = {username:username,pass:pass,submit:"true"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `wrong username and password` because your PHP not returning anything in ajax success.

**Whats wrong here:**

You are sending username and password in ajax request but checking by using `submit` input which is wrong because submit is not the part of ajax data.

You can also check what are you getting in ajax request in php as:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Here, you can solve the problem as:

```
if(count($_POST) > 0) // check $_POST array > 0 or not..
```

instead of:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // submit not available in $_POST
```

Answer (score 0):

The object data you are sending through Ajax to the PHP script does not have a key called "submit" and hence this part of the code will fail

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

Just remove that if statement and you will be fine... You can equally check whether you have data within the `$_POST` super global like `devpro` suggested in the comment below your question or just check for only the fields you sent within the `$_POST` variable.